# Why don't my prisoners leave infirmary?

Tags: prison-architect

My prisoners have been stuck in the infirmary for the last few hours, why?
[Screendump](http://puu.sh/1BzRB.png)

Comment: You might want to add some more detail to your question. I believe as is it would be very difficult if not impossible to answer.

Comment: Problem is, I don't really know what to ask about... They just don't want to leave the infirmary D:

Comment: From the picture, it looks like they're all in lockdown.  That means you'll need to get guards to move them either to their cells, or to the holding area.

Comment: And how do I do that? D:

Comment: Click on the prisoner, then right-click where you want them.  A guard will come and haul them to that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=199) where prisoners can get stuck in [medical beds](http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Medical_Bed). Workaround includes:

- changing the prisoner's (click the prisoner and right-click a cell)
- send a nurse to a prisoner
- deconstruct the bed and move the prisoner